# Word cookies game Python , why it's not counting my words even though it exist in the file?

Tags: python, file

im working on a word cookie game. i have a file with 429k english words but when i type my words it dosent count them not sure why. code is down below in Python

```
import random
from random import shuffle

letters = ["c", "a", "e", "r", "u", "o", "i", "n", "b"]
score = 0
game_on = True
f = open(r"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\wordlist.txt", "r")


def easy(letter_list, file):
    global score
    global game_on
    # unique_letters = [i for i in letter_list]
    # mode_letters = random.sample(unique_letters, 3)
    shuffle(letter_list)
    mode_letters = letter_list[:3]
    print(mode_letters)
    guess_word = input("combine the letters to form a word")
    for line in file:
        if guess_word in line:
            score += 1
            print("correct word you get a +1 to your score")
            print(score)
            return score
        else:
            print(" that's not a word start the game again")
            game_on = False
            return game_on

while game_on:
    print("hello welcome to word cookies game")
    difficulty = input("choose what difficulty you would like to have Easy / Medium / difficult").lower()
    if difficulty == "easy":
        easy(letters, f)
```

Comment: One problem is that `easy` returns on the first iteration, so it only ever sees the first line in the file.

Comment: isnt that fine? since it will run again as the while loop flag still running?

Comment: @Azizalfarhan No, it'll return **from the function**. In other words, it will not continue the loop. Return means to exit the function and return back to where it was called.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try commenting in your code to help others understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` breaks out of the function, not just the loop.
Your if/else has a return in either case, and since one or the other will *always* be evaluated on every iteration of the loop, it's guaranteed that you'll break out of the function prematurely.

What you might want is to get rid of the else - only check for success, and when that is not guaranteed for any case, *then* declare failure.

The second return seems unnecessary, especially since it's returning a different type (boolean) than the score (int), so I'd just get rid of that.

```py
for line in file:
    if guess_word in line:
        score += 1
        print("correct word you get a +1 to your score")
        print(score)
        return score
# after the for loop finishes we can safely say the word
# was not found in the file.
print("that's not a word start the game again")
game_on = False
```

Comment: great answer <3 thank you. opened my eyes

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this, or something similar:

```
file = open('File', 'r+')

words = file.readlines()
for word in words:
    words.replace(word, word.strip()) # To remove all the '\n' newline characters

if guess_word in words:
    score += 1
```

Assuming you have a different word on each line, this should work just fine.